# Android programming is not working in eclipse

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, adt, ubuntu-12.04

My Eclipse was working fine until i updated my sdk.Then suddently everything started to show little weirder.Actyually I was working in Ubuntu 12.04 ,Which stopped showing even Java projects after updation.When I click New-->Project  I can't find neither java/Android.I cant even find XML.I have done so many methods listed in some sites.But nothing is working for me.Can anyone please suggest a solution.

```
I have even tried in windows.But same problem happened & it says " Android Development Tools (20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.6.0)", or later version."
```

what to do?
please give me a solution

Thanking you in advance

Comment: download latest eclipse and latest ADT plugin for it

Comment: Try removing the workspace you are using. Don't forget to backup projects first

Comment: I installed all the updates .Still no solution.

Comment: I am now using a new workspace?is it necessary to remove the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//you need to download the eclipse 3.6 helios or 3.7 indigo

```
Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) or greater
Note: Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.
```

If you need to install Eclipse, you can download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. We recommend the "Eclipse Classic" version.

**Note:** creating new Workspace cleaning project, restarting wont work.

Comment: android stopped supporting 3.5. I am sure you are using galileo. so you need to download new version. there is no option to upgrade or update. so download and install the android plugins. :-)

Comment: I just downloaded new version called Juno .now when i was installing  the android plugin the following error just came '(com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
  Missing requirement: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found' what to do next?

Answer (score 2):

Update your ADT to ADT 20.0.0 Then its will solve your problem.please refer below link 
 http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: first you should remove you ADT through Eclipse and add new ADT through zip file

Comment: I has removed it & while re installing through  Zip file .I got the following error  ** 'Android Development Tools (20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires plug-in org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.6.0), or later version. ' **
I have added this link using add site.Bt it says that  
** error in connection** & error in address

Comment: Could you please check your eclipse version, ADT version try to install as new and your jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Your update process probably resulted in loss of installed plugins.

You must update your eclipse to the latest version and then find updated plugins, ADT etc.

This I believe should work out.

Cheers!